# How to make my Toolbar displays full tittle in two lines instead of displaying "..."

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I created a ScrollingActivity (A template activity of Android Studio). You can see the behavior in this short video  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5SYtCgqD1o)

I saw a few questions like this and the answer of them was to put a textView inside the toolbar to display a two lines tittle. I tried it but the problem is that I lose the scrolling toolbar behavior (which you can see in the video).

Here is my code, thank you!

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigation_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(b.getString("title"));
    toolbar.setSubtitle("2 hores");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a layout

**normal_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingBottom="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="14dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tittle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text=" some large text Vishwesh Jainkuniya"


                 />



    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now in your `Activity.java` under `onCreate` method

```
  Toolbar mToolbar;
  TextView tittle;

   mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   tittle= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tittle);

    tittle.setTitle("Some very very very very very very very very large text");
```

Now in your main layout looks

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include layout="@layout/normal_toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

Comment: Hei! Have you read my whole description? I tried to set a toolbar with TextView inside, but then the scrolling activity lose all its properties. Thank you!